# SAS SQL using a where condition with macro variable

Tags: sql, sas, where-clause

I have a `proc sql` procedure in SAS where my `where` clause should be dynamic (the set of ID numbers will be updated in the future).

I could do something as follows for a unique character condition:

```
%let value1=A ;
proc sql  ;
select * from sashelp.class
where upcase(name) contains symget('value1');
;
quit;
```

However, how could do the same to check several numbers? How could I make the following work?

```
%let value2= (11,12,13);
    proc sql  ;
    select * from sashelp.class
    where age not in symget('value2');
    ;
    quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve the value of VALUE2 before execution.

```
%let value2= (11,12,13);
proc sql  ;
   select * from sashelp.class
      where age not in &value2
      ;
   quit;
```

Comment: That works! In the interest of the community, why for the character we need to use `symget` and for numeric `&` would do?

Comment: You don't need to use SYMGET for either case if you enclose the character values in quotes "&value1".  All macro variables are strings.